# Displaying decimals as fractions using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I need to write a SELECT query for some users that will return a ratio.  The math involved would just be the simple division of two numbers.  However, they would like to have the ratio presented as a fraction rather than as a decimal.  What is the best way to do that in SQL using Oracle 10g?

Comment: Is `4 / 8` OK or does it need to be simplified to `1 / 2`?

Comment: How is this ratio stored? (ie: do you have both the denominator and the numerator?)

Comment: The fraction needs to be simplified, Mark.

Comment: And both numerator and denominator are stored in separate fields.  My query just needs to pull both of them and calculate the ratio.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can define a function in Oracle to calculate greatest common divisor ([taken from here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96595/dci05pls.htm)):

```
CREATE FUNCTION gcd (x INTEGER, y INTEGER) RETURN INTEGER AS
   ans INTEGER;
BEGIN
   IF (y <= x) AND (x MOD y = 0) THEN
      ans := y;
   ELSIF x < y THEN 
      ans := gcd(y, x);  -- Recursive call
   ELSE
      ans := gcd(y, x MOD y);  -- Recursive call
   END IF;
   RETURN ans;
END;
```

And then use that function in your SQL to concatenate a fraction string:

```
SELECT CAST(TRUNC(A / GCD(A, B)) AS VARCHAR2(10)) 
       || ' / ' || 
       CAST(TRUNC(B / GCD(A, B)) AS VARCHAR2(10)) AS FRACTION FROM TABLE
```